# Search between two SQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

### student

Columns

```
first_name
last_name
```

### teacher_accounts

Columns

```
fname
lname
```

I have an input form that takes the data entered into an input field, and passes it through the following SQL query:

```
select * from student WHERE first_name like '%$q%' OR last_name like '%$q%'
```

However, I want to now join the teacher_accounts table to see if the name entered possibly matches what is entered into the input field. Essentially I need an SQL statement that checks the teacher_accounts and student table against the data entered into the input field.

Thanks for any help!

### UPDATE

I need to mention that I'm outputting this data using mysql_fetch_array, so I need a way for the script to discern whether or not it needs to pull from the teacher columns or the student columns.

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<a href='?fname=".$row['first_name']."&lname=".$row['last_name']."'>".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."<br />";
```

Comment: Opening yourself up to all sorts of SQL injections.  Please see a better way to pass values to a query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, 'student' as `type`
FROM   students
WHERE  first_name like '%<your string>%'
   OR  last_name  like '%<your string>%'

UNION

SELECT fname, lname, 'teacher' as `type`
FROM   teacher_accounts
WHERE  fname like '%<your string>%'
   OR  lname like '%<your string>%'
```

Refer to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html for how to prepare statements and pass values safely using placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT
first_name AS `first`,
last_name AS `last`,
'student' AS `typeofaccount`
FROM Student
UNION
SELECT
fname AS `first`,
lname AS `last`,
'teacher' AS `typeofaccount`
FROM teacher_accounts
) AS u
WHERE 
first like '%$q%'
OR last like '%$q%'
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having errors with this syntax. it said all derived tables require aliases.

Comment: @zackt147: sorry I did not test it. I've edited the answer, please try it now

Comment: This syntax has pros and cons.  `pros`: you are filtering in one place, which might make it easier to edit in the future.  `cons`: it might be a little slower because you're pulling all records from both tables twice (first to give it an accounttype, then applying the filter).  I doubt the tables would be all the large, so longer query time might be minimal.

Comment: The syntax above might have errors.  I'm not sure if MySQL requires aliases to be wrapped in `\`\``, but the fields probably need to be separated by commas (`,`).

Comment: @vol7ron: syntax fixed, thank you! Also, I'm not sure what (if any) optimizations MySQL would use in the execution plan. I would probably choose the syntax you propose in your answer if the union between the two tables is only used in this query, the one I propose if there are other queries that need this union (in which case I would turn the inner query into a VIEW).